Windows 11 suddenly not recognizing Bluetooth device as sound output device
I have two Bose Headphones Quiet Comfort (2024)
Both of them connect fine on one laptop with Windows 11.
But on another laptop with Windows 11 only one of them works. It worked fine before but suddenly stopped working. Maybe through a Windows update. (System restore was unfortunately turned off)
I can connect the headphones but it won't play audio. If you click on the speaker icon in the taskbar, it will not show up as "Output Device"
I have factory reset the one headphone. The firmware is up do date.
The fact that both headphones essentially work well on one laptop, and that the problematic laptop can work with one of the headphones, implies to me, that there is maybe some "leftover connection" in Windows 11 that does not reset by removing the device from Bluetooth.

I suppose you already removed and re-paired the device?...

@ChanganAuto Of course. Not only once.
